# How create Row_Number in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I would like to generate an id that resets each time a group name changes (Address)

I have scenario in excel source like below:

```
ID    Name   Address
1     abc    Mumbai
2     def    Mumbai
3     efg    Pune
4     qwe    Satara
5     xsd    Satara
```

And after add excel file into excel source I want scenario like below

```
ID    RowID     Name   Address
1        1       abc    Mumbai
2        2       def    Mumbai
3        1       efg    Pune
4        1       qwe    Satara
5        2       xsd    Satara
```

Mumbai starts with 1, the next row is also Mumbai so it is 2 but Pune in the third row is not a member of the group so it resets to 1.

That is I want to execute `SQL query` for create `Row_Number` before data add into database for some purpose, But I don't know how to achieve this using `SSIS package`. So any give me direction to achieve this?

Comment: Unless I recall incorrectly, i think you *have* to use a script transformation for such tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Like Larnu commented you "can" to use a script component for this in SSIS. (You can also use SQL for your extract to do this, but this answer explains the SSIS method).

1st thing you need to do is sort your loaded data based on the RowNumber function (normally done in a sql order by).

for script component you need to define variables outside of row processing to store previous row.

```
string Name = "";
int RowID = 1;
```

Now inside row processing add code to check if current row matches previous row:

```
if(Row.Name == Name)
{
     RowID++; //increment counter
}
else //Reset everything
{
     Name = Row.Name;
     RowID = 1;
}

Row.RowID = RowID;
```

Comment: now that Bill formatted the data i can see clearly that you should test Address and not name.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to put sql command instead table into OLE DB Source with NEWID() function.
something like:
Select newid(), [ID Name Address]...
from tmp.table

and load this into destination table.